# Filter two measure groups based upon dimension of one

Tags: ssas, cube

I have the following scenario and want to understand how to do this in an SSAS cube,

I have a measure called "Number of Helpdesk Tickets Logged by an Employee" belongs to fact table FactHelpdesk ( This table has ticket number and employeekey) and have other measure called "Number Of Innovation Ideas Posted by an Employee" belongs to fact table "FactInnovation" (This fact table has idea number, idea status, innovation category and employeekey). 
Both these measures are based upon Employee ID dimension DimEmployee (this dimension has employee id, name,manager name etc).

When I see in cube browser count of helpdesk tickets and count of innovation ideas per manager it works fine, but there is a business requirement to see the above two count per manager but for only those employees of which innovation idea is in a complete status (i.e innovation.status='Completed').

Do I want to understand which are the ways to do this?
I think using calculated member is a way but is there any flexible way of doing this as tomorrow there may be another requirement of filtering these counts based upon the category of innovation idea etc.

Thanks

Comment: If i understand you correctly both tickets and innovation ideas are bound to specific employee. I recommend to include employee's innovation status into both measure table for tickets and innovation ideas. Create separate dimension called "Innovation status" and link that dimension to both measure groups. Now you are free to filter by both, manager and/or based on the innovation status.

Comment: Thanks I will analyse this further, Is there any other way to do this may be by defining some type of relationship in Dimension usage tab between Helpdesk and Innovation measure group? so that If I filter the resultset based upon an attribute of Innovation so that it will filter the heldesk measure group as well?

Comment: Dimension usage tab is the only way to define relationships between dimensions and measures. The relationship between two measures is expressed via their links to dimensions. If both ticket measure group and innovation measure group are linked to manager and innovation status dimensions, then you will get correct filtering every time you choose specific value from manager and/or innovation status.